# what is the best naming convention for a user control?" e.g. id="LblUserName", id="LabelUserName", or id="UserNameLabel"?

Tags: asp.net

what is the best way to call my controls?

LblUserName or LabelUserName or UserNameLabel

Comment: Do you mean "what is the best naming convention for a web control?" e.g. id="LblUserName", id="LabelUserName", or id="UserNameLabel"?

Comment: Why is everybody so fond of those prefixes? I thought we were past that phase?

Comment: I prefer UserNameLabel, SomethingTextBox, etc.  The only downside to this approach is that it's more to type.  Because text boxes are so common I'm not opposed to a "txt" prefix but if you follow that to the logical conclusion by doing things like "lbl", "chk", "cbo" it seems to take you too far in the Hungarian direction which is an eyesore AKAIC and hurts reability.  Quick: do you know what a "fsb" or "lwlst" is? One thing I try to remember is code is usually read more often than written, therefore favor read-time convenience over write-time convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For naming convention of a web control i usually follow this [Convention](http://www.visualize.uk.com/resources/asp-net-standards.asp)
The reasoning behind this is that when using Intellisnse, you will be able to see your controls grouped together due to the first letters. So when typing "lbl" you will see all your Label controls, etc...

Comment: I can use that same argument for private fields. Do you use prefixes for private member fields or method arguments?

Comment: Nah not really. Just habbit I guess.

Comment: "Just habbit I guess". LOL! +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you really and what are you used to, just be consistent whit naming. 
I name my controls like:

lblUsername, 
txtAddress, 
btnSave, 
chbRemeberMe, 
cmbCategory...

After some time you may not remember how and why you called something the way you did. But you may know that you are looking for textbox or button. Since we read from left to right, i think this way is better, more organised and easier to find controls.

Answer (score 0):

LblUserName is better way to call controls.

Answer (score 0):

General convention is to use `lblUserName` or `txtUserName`. Note the lowercase first letter.